# Apache POI XWPFRun.setText() does not work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to manipulate text runs in the XWPFDocument using Apache POI 3.10 and the method `XWPFRun.setText()` does not work the way I was expecting. This code:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(resp.getContent());
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
        int textPosition = run.getTextPosition();
        if (run.getText(textPosition) != null) {
            System.out.println("old value: " + run.getText(textPosition));
            run.setText("value changed", textPosition);
            System.out.println("new value: " + run.getText(textPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

produces the output:

```
old value: change me
new value: change me
```

What is the correct way of updating single run in XWPFDocument?

Comment: You don't appear to have any code writing the file out again after the changes - is it that simple?

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, it is that simple... However, I do not understand why it is required to store doc in a file in order to have changes applied.

Comment: Because that's how the library works - it loads it into memory, you make changes in memory, then you save. Just the same as Word - you need to tell it to save when you're done!

Comment: Nope. I make changes in memory using `setText()`, so I want to read from memory with `getText()`. For me it is quite obvious while using methods similar to getters and setters. And if you replace text in Word, you can see the replaced value without saving.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! What happens if you use `XWPFRun.toString()` to get the text out of the run, does that help? And have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: You do need to save to a file e.g. doc.write(new FileOutputStream(outfile));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's been a while and the explanation is somehow hidden between comments, so it may be worth to sum it up.*

Actually, there is no bug in Apache POI behavior. The problem is in the naming convention - although POI uses get/set methods, it does not mean that classes obey JavaBeans rules. In this example, `setText` method really does the job - all of the changes would be applied after saving edited document.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `run.toString()` to solve an issue similar to yours. (org.apache.poi 3.15) The output from `.toString()` is changed after `setText(..)` is called.

`System.out.println("toString(): " + run.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

### This is what worked for me:

```java
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
    for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
        int textPosition = run.getTextPosition();
        if (run.getText(textPosition) != null) {
            System.out.println("old value: " + run.getText(textPosition));
            run.setText("value changed", 0); // <<------ the difference is here
            System.out.println("new value: " + run.getText(textPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

The question owner said you had to save the document before you see changes, and the code was actually good. I didn't have to save anything, it just worked for me with a little difference:

**I had to pass `0` as `pos` argument in `run.setText`** instead of `textPosition` previously got from `run` so it overwrote the text.

(I also wanted to change the text, and for me `setText(String value)` appended text instead of replacing it, and `setText(String value, int pos)` did the job for me.)